# How can I use an absolute path to a network drive in a Visual Studio Code Multi-root workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With Visual Studio Code 1.73.1 i want to use the [multi-root-workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) feature to store my files on two different drives

1. the first folder `Workspace_1` is below the absolute path `C:\dev\vscode\multiroot-test\`
2. the second folder `Workspace_2` is below the absolute path `Y:\Dev\vscode\`. Y is a network drive in our company.

The file and folder structure is this

```
C:\dev\vscode\multiroot-test\
│               ├─ multiroot.code-workspace
│               └──Workspace_1
│                  └─── Hello_Workspace_1.txt
Y:\Dev\vscode\
         └──Workspace_2
            └─── Hello_Workspace_2.txt
```

The drive `Y` is a network folder under `\\my.corp\it_dep\usr\yours_truly`

#### Question

1. What is the syntax for an absolute path?
2. Are network drives supported?

#### What have i tried

My file `multiroot.code-workspace` contains this json

```js
{ 
  "folders": [    
     { "path": "C:/dev/vscode/multiroot_test" }, 
     { "path": "Y:/Dev/vscode/Workspace_2" }, 
  ],
  "settings": {}
}
```

But this does not work in my environment: the `Workspace_2` and the files below are not visible in vs code

[image: vscode_screenshot_workspace_2_not_visible]

Comment: have you tried to use `\\my.corp\it_dep\usr\yours_truly` as the path to the second folder, if not working create an issue at the VSC repo to ask how to do this and document it, have you added the second workspace through the **File** > **Add folder to Workspace**

Comment: Q1: No. Q2: No.  I tried your suggestions and this did the trick. I will add my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The user [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) hinted to test two options

1. to use the "network path" `\\my.corp\it_dep\usr\yours_truly` instead of the mapped drive `Y:`
2. to add the workspace from the menu (i added by creating the file manually).

So i did the following

1. i added the second workspace folder by using `File/Add Folder to Workspace ...` from the menu
2. i opened the folder using the network share adress `\\my.corp\it_dep\usr\yours_truly\Dev\vscode\Workspace_2`

Screen

[image: vscode multiroot workspace with network share]

The config file `multiroot_network_test.code-workspace` looks like this now

```json
{
 "folders": [
    { "path": "." },
    { "path": "\\\\my.corp\\it_dep\\usr\\yours_truly\\Dev\\vscode\\Workspace_2"}
 ],
 "settings": {}
}
```

And this is how it looks like in vscode

[image: vscode multiroot workspace]